# UIPopoverController and release in delegate-method; "potential memory leak"

Tags: ios, memory-management, uipopovercontroller

I'm doing an alloc/init with my UIPopoverController, then release it in the delegate method. Whenever I perform a "build and analyze", I get memory warnings with "potential leaks" - am I doing something wrong or is there a way to get rid of those warnings?

Thanks a lot!

```
- (void) somewhere {
    MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    UIPopoverController *popover=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];
    [vc release];

    // show the popover
    [popover presentPopoverFromRect:[cell frame] inView:self.tableView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    popover.delegate = self;
}

- (void) popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
   [popoverController release];
   popoverController = nil;
}
```

**EDIT:** show complete somewhere-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in the `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:` method you should **not** release the `popoverController` instance, since it will be released by the framework.

Second, what's the meaning of that `somewhere` method? You should post the complete implementation here ... I suppose you are showing up the popover view, so you should do something like this:

```
- (void) somewhere {

    // I suppose you have a local variable to hold the controller
    _myPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc]   initWithContentViewController:vc];
    _myPopover .delegate = self;

    // ... do other things to configure the popover, if necessary

    // I suppose you show it, with something like this
    [_myPopover presentPopoverFromRect:yourRect inView:yourView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES]; 
}
```

Then, when you no longer need the popover controller, you can release it. You could try with your code, this way:

```
- (void) popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    [_myPopover release];
    _myPopover = nil;
}
```

This way you will always hold the instance of the popover where you need it, and release it when you have finished with it. In your previous implementation that instance was not bound to anything.

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work. you must not release the UIPopoverController ("popover") there...

Comment: If you are not saving the `popover` instance locally in your class, you do not longer need it. Could you please post the whole source code for `somewhere`?

Comment: I still don't agree; if I put the release there, the app crashes. From other SO-questions: "UIPopoverController has a slight different memory management/owning. Present a popover does not retain the memory, so you can't transfer the ownership of your popviewcontroller to the presenting object."

Comment: You are right. And I was wrong ... I just updated the answer when a different solution. Please try it? I suggest you to hold the popover controller instance locally in your class.